# How to export Logic Pro tracks into an .m4a, .flac, or .mp3 file?

Tags: logic

It is a bit strange that in the File -> Export of Logic Pro, I can export all tracks into one file, but only as Wav, Aiff, CAF format.

However, I can share to Apple Music, and it will go into the Music app as .m4a

I can share to SoundCloud, and the upload is quite fast, so I think it is either .m4a or .flac or .mp3. (I just tried downloading my own file, and it was .m4a, but why upload first and download? And SoundCloud sometimes mark our own playing of classical piano music as "possible infringement of copyright" and won't include our work in our profile).

So how do we just save it as one of .mp3, .flac, or .m4a format without going through Apple Music or SoundCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Export is for your master file, not for lossy compressed formats. Save your master as WAV or AIF, then convert for streaming services as a separate step. The two structures also demand different mastering levels. 'CD' can have far higher LUFS values than streaming, so you master first for CD, then pull your levels back to satisfy -14dB LUFS streaming limits & be more careful monitoring for TruePeak levels, which are not so important for WAV as for compressed formats, where they can cause distorted peaks.

Comment: ok... isn't FLAC lossless too?  I suppose whether the user wants lossy or lossless is not for Logic Pro to decide. Some users may really want a 4.5MB file to upload to Google Drive to share with other, so if Logic Pro has that capability, why hide it?

Comment: Yes, FLAC is lossless, but there's no native Apple app that can use it, so why would Apple include it? I'm trying to differentiate your 'master' file from any you use for streaming. You really should make a real master from which all others are derived, not start with the streaming version, because they need to conform to different standards.

Comment: you are similar to saying when we take photos, every phone should be in uncompressed form. It just doesn't fit a user's purpose in that case.  Note that I am "exporting" to have a copy of some sort. Perhaps to send to a person to sample it. I cannot always send the person a 35MB file. Isn't it a choice that I can make to send a 4 to 5MB file? Now I have to dirty my Apple Music collection to have these `.m4a` files because "nope, export won't do it". If I am saving the project file, I can agree we want the most original form. But right now we are not. We are merely exporting a copy

Answer (score 0):

You can export the track to different codecs by hitting File -> Bounce and select the appropriate options.

Comment: I think bounce is to convert the internal MIDI into a wav form, and is included as part of the Logic Pro project file. I tried that and all of a sudden my 900kb project bumped up to 32MB

Comment: I dont know what exactly you chose and what settings, but that seems very weird indeed. I just bounced a 21mb Logic project to a 3mb mp3